# Java error:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner not org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Partitioner

at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setClass(Configuration.java:2273)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setPartitionerClass(JobConf.java:1165)

at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.setJobConf(StreamJob.java:944)

at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.run(StreamJob.java:128)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)

at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.HadoopStreaming.main(HadoopStreaming.java:50)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Attempting to fetch counters from logs...

Can't fetch history log; missing job ID

No counters found

Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...

Can't fetch history log; missing job ID

Can't fetch task logs; missing application ID

I am running into this error when I try to use partitioner class for keyfieldbasedpartitioner. My input and output formats are rawvalueprotocol and output is tab separated. 
Has anyone seen this before? please help.

Comment: Can you post how you're trying to run this job?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed when I used

`--partitioner", "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner",`